# Does Rundeck have to be online or I can simply host it on a local VM?

Tags: virtual-machine, rundeck

Does Rundeck have to be online or I can simply host it on a local VM? If it has to remain online, then why? or If it can be kept on a local VM would that work? if not, then why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rundeck needs to be online to execute the [workflows](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/job-workflows.html#job-workflows) that you define, whether in a virtual environment or not. Just make sure that the Rundeck instance can access the [remote](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/projects/node-execution/ssh.html#configuring-remote-machine-for-ssh) nodes.

A good way to test Rundeck is to use the [official Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/rundeck/rundeck).

Comment: In other words, as long as the jobs executed manually, it should be alright, yes?

Comment: Host in a virtual machine? Yes, sure. Same for scheduled jobs. If you want to run rundeck on certain moments, you can use the war file and start it with `java -jar rundeck.war`